# Question about OAuth 2.0 authorization flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization

I've been looking at this image from [Microsoft OAuth2 flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code) and I have a question

[image]

A browser dialog pops up where they enter their credentials and consent to permissions; in return i get an `authorizationCode`. With this `authorizationCode` I should make a request to `/oauth2/token` and get in exchange an `access_token` and a `refresh_token`.

In order to get the `access_token` and `refresh_token` I have to combine the `authorizationCode` with a `clientSecret`.

My question is: who should request the `access_token`? The **frontend** or the **backend**?

I get the `authorizationCode` and send it to backend that holds the `clientSecret` and does some magic and returns me the `access_token` that I can further use to validate against a WebAPI?
Or everything should be done on frontend and send to APIs the `access_token` directly?

Thank you!

Comment: Shury, have you found my answer useful or is there some problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best would be to use [Proof Key for Code Exchange](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) (PKCE) instead of a password. [Microsoft supports it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code), see `auth` request params `code_challenge` and `code_challenge_method`. Then there is the `code_verifier` parameter for the `token` endpoint, which you use instead of a password. There is also the [OAuth 2.0 for Native Apps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252#section-6) RFC which says:

> Public native app clients MUST implement the Proof Key for Code
> Exchange (PKCE [RFC7636]) extension to OAuth, and authorization
> servers MUST support PKCE for such clients

Example: Before making an auth request, you generate a random text (later used as the `code_verifier`), then you create its SHA-256 hash (use as `code_challenge`) and you let the auth server know that you used SHA-256 with `&code_challenge_method=S256`. The auth server keeps these values and when you ask the `token` endpoint for tokens, it will create its own SHA-256 hash out of the `code_verifier` value. If the hash equals the `code_challenge` you sent before, the server will accept the request.